# Use of /opt and /usr/local directories in the context of a PC

Tags: filesystem, directory

What is the difference between `/opt` and `/usr/local` directories and what kind of programs should be installed to them?

I referred to [Linux File-system Hierarchy](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/) but the explanation is not that clear.
According to above link;

`/opt` :- This directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages that are not part of the default installation

`/usr/local` :- The `/usr/local` hierarchy is for use by the system administrator when installing software locally. It needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system software is updated.

In the context of a PC without any networked computers what should be the directory to install a software that will be accessed by multiple local users? (i.e. where should I install a software like netbeans)

Thank you

Comment: Google Chrome `opt`s to use that directory for some reason.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I guess it's `opt`ional.

Comment: @becko Well, it must be an `opt`imal choice if Google ad `opt`ed it.

Comment: Even if you all where right, `opt` imus Prime sounds better.

Comment: Similar question in [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34880/use-of-opt-and-usr-local-directories-in-the-context-of-a-pc), [superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/122420/usr-local-or-opt), [unix&linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11544/what-is-the-difference-between-opt-and-usr-local)

Comment: Lol..I came late to the party ..But it seems like you people have `opt` imized the comments section a lot..:P

Answer (score 92, accepted):

`/opt` is for third-party applications that don't rely on any dependencies outside the scope of said package. `/usr/local` is for packages installed on this machine outside the scope of the distribution package manager.

An example:

An open source sip-client supplied as a .deb would install into `/usr`. If it was built with the Qt framework, apt would pull it in as a dependency.

The same open source sip-client built from source would reside in `/usr/local`so it would not be messed up by apt if you later installed a .deb package for the same application. You could either build its dependencies from source, or get them from the package manager.

A third-party application in `/opt` is supposed to be self-contained. For instance, a proprietary sip-client using Qt would not rely on the version from apt, but would have it bundled or statically linked in.

For more information, take a look at the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).

Comment: so netbeans goes to /usr/local as it depends on jdk and other compilers + plus it follows linux FHS?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: If i want to install [`conda`](https://conda.io/docs/) globally as suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27364203/898649), is `/opt` the right place?

Comment: @Egil, Why doesn't mac have an opt directory?

Comment: I previously upvoted this answer, but I now see that its conclusions differ slightly from [this *Linux Journal* article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/pointcounterpoint-opt-vs-usrlocal). The article implies that with packaged software, *it matters who supplied the package*. If the package is from the OS's package repo, then it should be installed under `/usr` (or, presumably, even directly under `/bin`, `/lib`, etc) as usual. If, however, it is from another source, then it should be put into `/usr/local`. That would potentially include the "open source sip-client" `.deb` in the answer.

Comment: @sampablokuper The `.deb` file would be installed using the package management system of the OS which installs it to `/usr` and maintains the info of its origin as well as the way of uninstalling it. (The linked article speaks about it pretty much.) However, if the binary were distributed as a `.tar.gz`, for example, then you should unpack it to `/usr/local`.

Answer (score 14):

I would install third-party binary-only packages to `/opt`.

Anything you build yourself from source I would put in `/usr/local`.

`netbeans` is in the Ubuntu Repos. Do you need a specific version?

Comment: Is there any rationale behind it or is it just a good practice? (I mentioned netbeans as an example - I changed that part to remove any ambiguities). Thank you

Comment: I think other answers have said it best. Usually third-party binaries are self-contained.

Comment: What about things that depend on runtimes, like Python or Java software? I'd put them on `/opt` but am not sure if it's correct.

Answer (score 11):

It's all about packaging. If something is packaged in the LHS way (putting executables into bin/ libraries into lib/ etc.) it should go into /usr/local.

If something has a top level directory and doesn't follow that model, it goes in /opt. Generally, you have to explicitly add stuff in /opt to your PATH.

See also [This question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/122420/usr-local-or-opt)

Comment: This answer seems to be corroborated by [this *Linux Journal* article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/pointcounterpoint-opt-vs-usrlocal).

Comment: or add symlinks from /usr/local/bin?

Comment: You could do that, but it isn't exactly the same thing. If there is a script, and it calls another executable by just the name, then PATH works, but symlinks (of just the first script) would not.