# How to update FileZilla on Ubuntu?

Tags: filezilla

Until now the FileZilla software on my PC is version 3.3.5.1

[image]

But on FileZilla's website http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client

the latest version is 3.5.1 now.

I have check the packages website and Synaptic Package Manager on my Ubuntu. My FileZilla is same on package.
http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/filezilla

But I want to install the latest FileZilla on Ubuntu. Not version 3.3.5.1 by 2010. Because I use FileZilla frequently. So I think it is an important software to me.

But what can I do for updating my FileZilla now?

Do I need to build from Source? Or some other choice?

Can someone help me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[It's in this repository.](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/programs-ppa)

You can add the repository and install it with the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

All LTS packages have been moved here (for easier rebuilding):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa2
```

Comment: Outdated: Does not provide latest version for Xenial (16.04 LTS).

Comment: I encountered a bug in Filezilla. After the update, it is fixed.

Comment: This is not a good solution as there is no release for Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use the official `flathub` version, it will be updated automatically: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.filezillaproject.Filezilla

Install it from the command line:

```
flatpak install flathub org.filezillaproject.Filezilla
```

Install from Ubuntu Software store:

- Search for `FileZilla`
- click `install` (on the flathub version!)
- done.

Comment: The command line gives:  `Command 'flatpak' not found, but can be installed with:`
`sudo apt install flatpak`       So, I tried,   `sudo apt install flathub org.filezillaproject.Filezilla`  Which gives:
`[sudo] password for geoffrey: `
`Reading package lists... Done`
`Building dependency tree       `
`Reading state information... Done`
`E: Unable to locate package flathub`
`E: Unable to locate package org.filezillaproject.Filezilla`
`E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'org.filezillaproject.Filezilla'

Comment: For those who don't yet have `FlatPak` installed (most readers), you must do this **first:**  https://flatpak.org/setup/Ubuntu  .  And then install here:  https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.filezillaproject.Filezilla  or use command line `flatpak install flathub org.filezillaproject.Filezilla` @GeoffreyWheeler

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions here:  https://engineerworkshop.com/blog/how-to-update-install-filezilla-on-ubuntu/
This in itself is not a complete answer.
If you don't have an .opt directory then you need to create one.  Here's why and how:  [Use of /opt and /usr/local directories in the context of a PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34880/use-of-opt-and-usr-local-directories-in-the-context-of-a-pc)
One must also add the installed directory to $path ([How do I add an executable to my search path?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/322772/how-do-i-add-an-executable-to-my-search-path)) and add it to the GUI menu system ([Add executable file to lubuntu menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742586/add-executable-file-to-lubuntu-menu)).