# How do I install filezilla?

Tags: 13.04, software-installation, filezilla

I want to install FileZilla. I can find it in Ubuntu Software Center but not download button. Using Ubuntu Dash I can't find a download button either.

Using terminal it doesn't work because I only found instructions for Ubuntu 12 (but I am on 13.04).

Answer (score 92):

Filezilla is already available in default repos of Ubuntu 13.04

You can try this

```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install filezilla


nischay@NischayLaptop:~$ apt-cache search filezilla

filezilla - Full-featured graphical FTP/FTPS/SFTP client
filezilla-common - Architecture independent files for filezilla

nischay@NischayLaptop:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.04"
```

Comment: As of July 2016 my filezilla says it's "up to date" at the command line, but in the help>about menu it says that the build date is Sept 2013.  This version is very far behind the version in windows, and doesn't have many basic features such as using a .pem key as a password.

Comment: @geneorama For me the `Build date` is 2016-02-25.

Comment: @OmarTariq My point is that the software update wasn't updating Filezilla for me, which seems to be happening to you too. I believe resolved the issue using this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/60701/71633

Comment: outdated version.

Answer (score 7):

To install FileZilla, you just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

Comment: what the first line of code do?

Comment: It adds the repository.

Comment: The version in this repository is outdated. It’s from 2013. In this case, installing the software from the default repositories is better.

Comment: unless pressing reasons, stick with the standard repo [above](https://askubuntu.com/a/339985/479118)

Comment: outdated version.

Answer (score 4):

For latest version of filezilla use below example of *filezilla version 3.10.1.1*

```
wget sourceforge.net/projects/filezilla/files/FileZilla_Client/3.10.1.1/FileZilla_3.10.1.1_i586-linux-gnu.tar.bz2   
tar -xjvf FileZilla_3.10.1.1_i586-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
```

Note extracting folder. Here is *filezilla3*

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/filezilla*
sudo mv **FileZilla3** /opt/**filezilla3**
sudo ln -sf /opt/**filezilla3**/bin/filezilla /usr/bin/filezilla
filezilla
```

Comment: This is the best method. The Ubuntu repos often have outdated versions and this is the best way to install the latest one

Comment: With this method I'm getting filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Use offilcial LInk : https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?show_all=1

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to install filezilla is via ppa

open terminal and type the following commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/programs-ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

for more details visit

http://dctutors.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-filezilla-373-on-ubuntu.html

Comment: unless pressing reasons, stick with the standard repo [below](https://askubuntu.com/a/339985/479118)

Comment: outdated version.

Answer (score 0):

The command to install filezilla in obsolete ubuntu is:

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list ....
```

After this paste these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo aptitude install filezilla
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

Now filezilla is available in **Ubuntu Software**.

**Alternate:**

You can download the file directly from https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client

1. Extract it
2. Keep in a folder
3. Create a .desktop file
4. Move .desktop file to application folder

More info:

1. As of now the file is *FileZilla_3.56.0_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.bz2* . Extract it to your required folder, it can be in your home folder.
2. My file location is */home/sudhakar/Soft/FileZilla_3.56.0_x86_64-linux-gnu/FileZilla3*
3. &4.: Then create a *filezilla.desktop* file at */home/sudhakar/.local/share/applications*

**filezilla.desktop**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=FileZilla
GenericName=FTP client
GenericName[da]=FTP-klient
GenericName[de]=FTP-Client
GenericName[fr]=Client FTP
Comment=Download and upload files via FTP, FTPS and SFTP
Comment[da]=Download og upload filer via FTP, FTPS og SFTP
Comment[de]=Dateien über FTP, FTPS und SFTP übertragen
Comment[fr]=Transférer des fichiers via FTP, FTPS et SFTP
Exec=filezilla
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;
Version=1.0

Exec=/home/sudhakar/Soft/FileZilla_3.56.0_x86_64-linux-gnu/FileZilla3/bin/filezilla
StartupNotify=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
Icon=/home/sudhakar/Soft/FileZilla_3.56.0_x86_64-linux-gnu/FileZilla3/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps/filezilla.svg
```

**Finally:**
Check it in app launcher. If it's not there just logout and login. It should appear in app launcher.

**NOTE:** This will be available for current user only. If you want to install for all the users in the PC. **(2)** Move the extracted folder to **/opt** directory (it requires *admin permission*. In terminal - `sudo mv '/home/sudhakar/Soft/FileZilla_3.56.0_x86_64-linux-gnu/FileZilla3' '/opt'`). Also move the **filezilla.desktop** file to **/usr/share/applications** folder. **Before moving** update ***Exec=*** and ***Icon=*** location.