# How do I add an executable to my search path?

Tags: paths

For reference, I know very little about Linux, and am using it to run a program written by someone else. The instructions say `Add the executable 'ttt' to the search path. In most installations this can be accomplished by linking the file to the 'bin' subdirectory at user home.`

How do I go about doing this?

This executable is currently in  a subfolder in the host area, as it's running on a dual-boot computer I cannot change the fact that it is a dual boot, as it is a work computer.

Answer (score 42):

**To make this work for the command line (terminal):**

I would suggest that you do the following steps in the terminal:

1. **Create a folder called `bin` in your home directory.**

   ```
   mkdir ~/bin
   ```
2. **Add `~/bin` to your `PATH`** for all sessions of Bash (the default shell used inside of the terminal).

   ```
   $ nano ~/.bashrc

   # Add the following to the end of your .bashrc file while using nano
   # or your text editor of choice:

   export PATH="/home/$USER/bin:$PATH"
   ```
3. **Add either the executable files themselves OR symlinks to the executable** into `~/bin`
4. **Restart your terminal session by closing out the terminal and reopening it, or run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the configuration for your session**

That should allow your terminal to read the `PATH` variable for terminal sessions.

I do not know how to add it to the GUI, though, as I'm not certain of how the GUI manages the `PATH` variable(s), but it might be necessary to modify the path with other methods should this method here not work with the GUI.

Comment: Can't you just `source ~/.bashrc` instead of closing and reopening the terminal?

Comment: @wordsforthewise you can, yes.  (Considering I wrote this well over 3 years ago when I wasn't the linux professional I am now, I hadn't known that heh.  (Adding shortly)

Comment: @wordsforthewise some imperfect `~/.bashrc`'s behave strangely when sourced twice.

Comment: @styrofoamfly that's why you never have an imperfect ~/.bashrc ;)

Comment: I think the answer could be improved if you added an example of point 3 as symlinks aren't so commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

to just temporary add the local directory to your path call this:

```
PATH="$(pwd):$PATH"
```