# Add executable file to lubuntu menu

Tags: lubuntu, executable, appmenu

I would like to add the gapminder executable file to the lubuntu menu, with as little terminal use as possible... Is there any way to do this? Here is an attached image of the file:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get this `gapminder` from? How did you install it? Seems like a Windows program because of `application.ini` in your image.

Comment: I got it from: http://www.gapminder.org/world-offline/  When I click on the file it asks if I want to run it as an executable, and I click on it and it opens as the application...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in my opinion is this:
Open directory /usr/share/applications with sudo rights (easiest way with command 'gksu pcmanfm', gksu must be installed) and create the file appname.desktop and put this inside:

[Desktop Entry]
Name='appname'
Exec=/'path-to-app'/'appname'
Terminal=false
Type=Application

The menu will detect it automatically (a reboot may be needed).