# How do I install utorrent on ubuntu 14.04 other instructions seem specific to older versions of the os

Tags: 14.04, utorrent

I have tried following some of the step by step instructions given but I think some of eh codes and instructions that need to be entered into the terminal window may be specifically for older versions of the Ubuntu operating system

Comment: Which instructions ? last I looked utorrent was a windows client that ran on wine and with numerous linux native clients, why not use a linux native client?

Comment: I would strongly recommend **Deluge**, which is in *Ubuntu Software Centre* (for 14.04).

Comment: just followed this exaclty and i get the below sudo: utorrent: command not found what have i done wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There isn't (yet) a 14.04 package from the µTorrent team.

Instead you have to work with the 13.04 package, which you can download from [HERE](http://www.utorrent.com/downloads/complete/type/utserver/os/linux-i386-ubuntu-13-04/track/beta).

make sure you have libssl installed:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libssl0.9.8
```

extract your downloaded tarball to `/usr/local`:

```
cd /usr/local && sudo tar -xzf /path/to/utserver.tar.gz
```

symlink that into place:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ /usr/local/utorrent/
```

extract the webUI and set up the necessary subdirectories:

```
cd /usr/local/utorrent
sudo unzip webgui.zip
sudo mkdir maint torrents.queue torrents.active
```

copy and paste this example configuration file into `/usr/local/utorrent/utserver.conf` using your editor of choice (e.g. `vim`, `nano`, `gedit`):

```
dir_root: /usr/local/utorrent/
ut_webui_dir: /usr/local/utorrent/webui/
dir_active: /usr/local/utorrent/torrents.active/
dir_completed: /home/<userid>/Downloads/
dir_temp_files: /usr/local/utorrent/tmp
dir_autoload: /usr/local/utorrent/torrents.queue/
dir_request: /usr/local/utorrent/maint
```

You can now start µTorrent like this:

```
sudo utorrent -settingspath /usr/local/utorrent/
```

And connect to the webUI at `localhost:8080/gui` with `admin` and no password (change that immediately).

**EDIT: 201405241343Z:** replaced `opt` with `usr/local` as more idiomatic for debian/ubuntu

Comment: /opt is not a common or standard location to install something like this, generally Debian/Ubuntu uses /usr/local . There is a nice, more technical discussion here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/34880/use-of-opt-and-usr-local-directories-in-the-context-of-a-pc . As you are using libssl0.9.8 installed from apt, /usr/local is the preferred location. In practice, as long as one understands $PATH I am not really sure it makes a difference.

Comment: Edited to reflect the more idiomatic debian/ubuntu path.

Comment: Running any server software as root is really bad advice. You should create a new user (`adduser`) and run it as that user.

Comment: Yes, that is true. It is also outside of the scope of this question. I don't think it's unreasonable to expect users to make their own decisions about system administration best-practices.

Answer (score 1):

The current webui.zip extract to folders ./web/ and ./mobile/

`ut_webui_dir: /usr/local/utorrent/webui/`

will not work.
You have to 
`unzip webui.zip && mv web webui`

and update your config to 
`ut_webui_dir: /usr/local/utorrent/`

to point to the parent directory. That's how I got it to work.

Also helpful when executing add `-daemon` and `-logfile /usr/local/utorrent/utorrent.log` options

Thanks for the howto, regardless
Cheers,

A script to create an upstart to run the process so all you have to do a is `sudo service utorrent start`

`cat << EOF > /etc/init/utorrent.conf

description "Start utorrent server process"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

exec /usr/local/utorrent/utserver -settingspath /usr/local/utorrent/ \
           -logfile /usr/local/utorrent/utserver.log \
           -pidfile /usr/local/utorrent/utserver.pid
EOF
`