# uTorrent server only working with 'sudo -i' option

Tags: command-line, 14.04, server, sudo, utorrent

Apparently it's not a working/not working issue.

I have setup uTorrent server in my Xubuntu 14.04 following these instructions.
[How do I install utorrent on ubuntu 14.04 other instructions seem specific to older versions of the os](https://askubuntu.com/a/471227/145915)

Worked great except for two things that had to change from the original set of instructions
1. The configuration specified there says the WebGUI folder is in

> /usr/local/utorrent/webui/
>   When it actually should be web since no specifications were given during the unzip operation

2. I have to start uTorrent each time with the following command

   sudo -i utorrent -settingspath /usr/local/utorrent/

Now why is that? As far as I know sudo -i option is used so that the dotfiles of the root user are used. But how come this is not required by the original poster?

Comment: Just a comment: It is a *really* bad idea to run uTorrent (or any server software for that matter) as root, even if the linked post instructed you to. That is really bad advice. You should create a separate user using `adduser` and run uTorrent as that user. You don't even need to install it into `/usr/local`, just put uTorrent in the new user's home directory.

Comment: @JeremieMiserez That seems to go a long way--and perhaps the whole way---toward answering this question. You might want to post it, or something very much like it, as an answer.

Comment: @EliahKagan Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **It is a really bad idea to run uTorrent (or any server software for that matter) as root**, even if the linked post instructed you to. That is really bad advice. You should create a separate user using `adduser` and run uTorrent as that user. You don't even need to install it into `/usr/local`, just put uTorrent in the new user's home directory.
2. Is uTorrent *really* what you need? It is closed source and hasn't been regularly updated. There are various open-source clients available, even the default `Transmission` has a web interface.

Here is how I'd do it. Of course if you want a service etc. you'd need to look that up separately. This is just the very simple version:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install libssl0.9.8
$ sudo adduser torrent
$ sudo cp ~/Downloads/utserver.tar.gz /home/torrent/
$ sudo su - torrent
$ ln -s ~/utorrent-server-alpha-v3_3/ ~/utorrent
$ cd ~/utorrent
$ unzip webui
$ mkdir maint torrents.queue torrents.active
$ cat << EOF > ~/utorrent/utserver.conf
dir_root: /home/torrent/utorrent/
ut_webui_dir: /home/torrent/utorrent/webui/
dir_active: /home/torrent/utorrent/torrents.active/
dir_completed: /home/torrent/Downloads/
dir_temp_files: /home/torrent/utorrent/tmp
dir_autoload: /home/torrent/utorrent/torrents.queue/
dir_request: /home/torrent/utorrent/maint
EOF
$ ./utorrent/utserver -settingspath /home/torrent/utorrent/ &
$ exit
```

Now uTorrent runs as user `torrent`, the web UI is available on `localhost:8080/gui`, user `admin`, no password. Files will be downloaded to `/home/torrent/Downloads/`. If you need to download to any other directory, make sure that the `torrent` user has write permissions to the directory. If you have a desktop interface installed, you could also run it as your desktop user.

You can stop the server forcibly by issuing `sudo pkill utserver` (which will kill uTorrent), or whatever the recommended way to stop it is.

Comment: I know the whole idea could, should and would go with permissions. And this method is probably a bulletproof one, taking out all the risks. So thanks.

I need to use uTorrent mostly because this one is most compatible with the private trackers in my country. That's it. I originally am just an aria2 user and loved it.

Comment: Make sure to add a password after you're done, the default is no password.