# How do I install JDK 1.5?

Tags: java, jdk

I am getting this error when trying to install java 1.5 JDK

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java5-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java5-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  apt:i386 apt

E: Package 'sun-java5-jdk' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Java 1.5 is too old. Try `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk`.

Comment: I need to javajdk 1.5 to run a specific application @user68186

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jdk-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR) JDK 5

Create directory for JDK:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm/java5
```

Extract archive in a new folder:

```
sudo tar xf java5.tar.gz -C /usr/lib/jvm/java5
```

Now run:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0/bin/java" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0/bin/javac" 1
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0/bin/javaws" 1
```

Correct the file ownership and the permissions of the executables:

```
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/java
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javac
sudo chmod a+x /usr/bin/javaws
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/jvm/java5/jdk1.5.0
```

Check if it successful:

```
java -version
```

Comment: This is what I am searching for tq for ur answer I will accept as soon as I get it done without getting any errors :)

Comment: @dhanvi If you will have some problem ask me here

Comment: I would suggest you put it in `/opt` rather than `/usr`. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/34880/use-of-opt-and-usr-local-directories-in-the-context-of-a-pc

Comment: @user68186 Check this **[answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74652/50478)**; `/usr/lib/` - *Libraries for programming and packages...*

Comment: `/usr/lib` is where package-managed software goes. These get installed by *Ubuntu Sotware Center*, `apt-get` or `dpkg`. It is best not to put stuff there manually.

Comment: Seconding user68186. Software outside of package management should go into `/usr/local` or `/opt`.

Comment: @AntonDozortsev  the alternate method doesn't work for me. FYI I've java 1.7 installed in my pc. Can you please make sure that the second method is still valid?

Comment: @mostafiz Now is invalid. Please follow by manual way.