# I have software (blender 2.76b) running as an "executable" from my home/documents folder. Should I move it to opt? ( (k)ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: filesystem, blender

I'm running (k)ubuntu 14.04 and everything I've read tells me to install 3rd party software in opt. everything is working fine but I want to know if I'm going to encounter problems later with add-ons and what not?

Comment: If you are on a single user system, you can keep it where you wish. On a multiuser system where you want others to use it, it should be owned by root and put in a general location. Personally I use /usr/local but you can use /opt if you wish, personal choice really.

Comment: You answered my question, but stack exchange is not giving me the option of voting it up, but thank you!

Comment: how do I say "answered".

Comment: converted my comment into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a single user system, you can keep it where you wish.

I personally tend to use `$HOME/bin` for scripts or personal binaries, make the directory if needed.

You then make sure $HOME/bin is on your $PATH by adding the following to ~/.bashrc

```
if [ -d $HOME/bin ]; then
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

you can add a custom launcher if needed, see [How do I add a custom launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78730/how-do-i-add-a-custom-launcher)

On a multiuser system where you want others to use it, it should be owned by root and put in a general location. Personally I use `/usr/local` but you can use `/opt` if you wish, personal choice really.

See The  Filesystem Hierarchy Standard with the technical difference between the two is discussed here - [Use of /opt and /usr/local directories in the context of a PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34880/use-of-opt-and-usr-local-directories-in-the-context-of-a-pc)

From https://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard

> /opt/ Add-on application software packages  Pre-compiled, non ".deb"
>   binary distribution (tar'ed..) goes here. /opt/bin/ : Same as for
>   top-level hierarchy /opt/include/ : Same as for top-level hierarchy
>   /opt/lib/ : Same as for top-level hierarchy /opt/sbin/ : Same as for
>   top-level hierarchy /opt/share/ : Same as for top-level hierarchy
>
> /usr/local/ : Tertiary hierarchy for local data installed by the
>   system administrator /usr/local/bin : locally compiled binaries, local
>   shell script, etc. /usr/local/src : Source code (place where to
>   extract and build non debian'ized stuffs)

For example, some people use /usr/local/src for kernel source from kernel.org. I use $HOME so that I do not need to use root to compile the kernel.

Again on a personal or family computer it makes little difference. If you  are taking a RHEL certification test or working on a large corporate system it may.