# What's the most appropriate directory where to place development software shared between users?

Tags: users, user-management, directory-structure, fhs

For sharing **data** files and directories among users within the same machine, the `/srv` directory was recommended here:

- [What's the most appropriate directory where to place files shared between users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70700/whats-the-most-appropriate-directory-where-to-place-files-shared-between-users)

I am assuming this is still valid or recommendded — correct me if that changed.

But what should be the directory for shared development-related **software** like Java, Maven, Gradle? They will all be installed by unpacking `.tar.gz` archives. A central location for programs would be preferred over repeated installations by each user in their respective home directory.

As an example, in order to work with CI like Jenkins I would have installed many JDK versions: 11, 15 and 17, and similarly for Gradle and Maven. These are used to test a project with different environments. The mentioned software packets are installed simply by unpacking the `.tar.gz` files and updating the `.profile` file with the respective settings for them. And yes, I use these repositories as well to install servers, such as MySQL, RabbitMQ etc ...

Comment: Read `man hier` to learn about the Linux Filesystem Hierarchy .

Comment: I suppose that the software is not available through the package manager?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since these software projects are installed by extracting a `.tar.gz` file it sounds like they are self-contained applications and I would install them in `/opt/<project>`.  Another common choice is `/usr/local`, but I prefer that for source based installs.

**Links**

- [Use of /opt and /usr/local directories in the context of a PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34880/use-of-opt-and-usr-local-directories-in-the-context-of-a-pc)
- https://codeghar.com/blog/should-your-software-go-in-usr-local-or-opt.html
- https://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/c23.html

Answer (score 4):

Put it in `/usr/local/`, it is ignored by package managers.